# Magento 2: Checkout page error Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/form/element/email"

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, checkout-page, guest-checkout

I am trying to find this error through var/log and disable custom overriding.

[image]

But this not able to find the issue. Can u Please help me it?

Comment: Have you already tried if the problem stil exists if you enable the default Luma theme? Most probably a problem in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/form/element/email.js` file exists.
2. If the file exists, then try to remove static content files and re-deploy static content:

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```